# Passing an instance of a list through forms C#

Tags: c#, forms, list

I have a class called Car which takes the parameters (string build, string manufacturer, string colour). I also have a list of Cars, in which all cars are stored. The cars are displayed in a form, along with their data. Everything works correctly. I have two forms, the main form which displays the cars, and another form where it is possible to add a new car, or modify an existing one.

On the first form, it is possible to right click a car and select edit. I am trying to pass an instance of the selected car from the first form, to the second form. It expects 1 parameter (Car selectedCar). I am finding it difficult however to send the instance to the second form where it is possible to modify the build, manufacturer, colour, ect. How can I go about this? I have been trying for hours and it is boggling my mind.

I will highly appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all of the comments. Here's some code and just a more in detail explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have two forms:
**Main Form** - Displays cars and their corresponding information. Cars are stored in a list of Cars. I have a Cars class which expects strings of build, manufacturer, and car. currently has set properties. It is possible to select a car here, to edit later. Or to add a new form.

** Add & Edit Form ** - If on the Main Form the Add New Car button has been clicked, this form allows a new Car to be added, it has text fields for Build, Manufacturer, and Colour. Upon submitting this form, the data is sent back to the Main Form, where is is then added to the list of cars.

(THIS IS WHAT I'M SEEKING HELP ON) - If the user selects a car and clicks edit, the Add & Edit form shows, and the text fields are populated with the corresponding data, that already exists in the Cars list for each particular car, so .. build, manufacturer, and colour.

On the Main Form, I need to send the selected car (which is assigned to _SelectedCar) to the Add & Edit Form, to populate the text fields, so that they can be edited.

CODE:
(This is the code that runs when the CarForm is initiated with 1 argument, that being the Car stored from the MainForm.

```
public partial class CarForm : Form
    {
    Car storedCar;
    bool editMode;
    public  CarForm(Car storedCar):this()
        {
            this.storedCar = storedCar;
            this.Text = "Edit Car";
            editMode = true;
            carBuildText.Text = storedCar.Build;
            carManufacturerText.Text = storedCar.Manufacturer;
            carColour.Text = storedCar.Colour;
        }
}
```

In the MainForm, when the edit button is clicked, the current code is run, however it does not work. The specific selected car is assigned to _storedCar

```
private void editCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CarForm carForm = new CarForm(_storedCar)
        }
```

So _StoredCar, possesses all the information about the Car, it's build, manufactuer, and colour. So I'm just trying to pass it through by initiating the form with the data of the car, and then accessing the data from the Add & Edit Form.

I am able to Add a new Car from the Add & Edit Form, and pass it back to the Main Form, but I'm struggling to populate the Add a Car Form from the Main Car.

Sorry for this long winded post.

Comment: yes its possible and How are we supposed to help?

Comment: There isn't anything special in WinForms that would prevent you from doing that - just pass the instance. Or show us your attempt in code.

Comment: This is trivial to do and it sounds like you are already most of the way there. Please post the relevant sections if code and describe what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Definitely post some code.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I have posted some code, I'm sorry for how long winded it is.

Comment: @DWright - i have posted some code, I apologise for how long winded it is

Comment: Ok, when you say it does not work, what do you mean?  Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the commenters are better people than I am, and they want you to post the code to help analyze what you are doing and give you the necessary pointers. I am in an enabling mood this morning, so I am going to list things you can do, but leave it to you to figure out the how since there is no real code.

You have two methods before you that you can try.

1) **The Hot Potato method.** 
   Whatever the element your user is clicking on in the first form to select a Car, if you are binding that list to the cars directly you can get a reference to the car from that items data item. Then you can pass that to your second form.

2) **Sharing is Caring**
   If you cant reference the Car from the list, or you want that list of cars to have significance outside of just the first form, then create a third static class to hold that list. When someone clicks on an item in the first form, using whatever identifier you have handy from that item, find the item itself in the static class and pass that to the second form.

Note that is either situation, the UI on the first form may or may not display the changes right away depending on if you are using databinding, and if so what binding properties are being used.

Answer (score 0):

What is the relation of two forms? Does 2nd form opens after certain event? In that case you could pass the list or selected item through the constructor to the other form.

Or you can **make your list a static field** to be shared between all of your forms. You could use a **static string variable** or something that holds current selected item and then you can use it in other forms.